# I can't upload my Play application on GAE : appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.4.0.jar too large to upload

Tags: google-app-engine, playframework

I use the play-gae module.
I tried to delete this jar from lib directory => error 500 during execution (ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceFactory).

So, it seems that this jar is necessary...

I find a discussion about this here : http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/msg/d103ebc5a789efc1 but no solution.

I must split this jar ? Pfff... ;-) Everybody do that ?

Comment: Have you tried to deploy without this jar and executed the production code? Or you just deleted the jar and run the code in your local machine?

Comment: I tried with production environment. ClassNotFoundException is on GAE server

Comment: This is strange. So this Play Framework need the GAE Dev Server even to run code in production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use a separate install of GAE with a more recent version. I have version 1.5 installed and I'm uploading my app without error:

```
play gae:deploy --gae=/Users/javierhe/Java/gae-sdk-1.5.0
```

Comment: In fact, I already use sdk 1.5 for deploy. But the play-gae module (last version, 1.4), came with appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.4.0.jar.

Comment: I tried again, with option --enable_jar_splitting, but no change :-(

Comment: Could you post information about your system, in order to compare it with other working systems?  In my case, i'm using MacOSX, with the provided JVM, playframework-1.2.3, and play-gae-1.4. Also, can you post the standard output of the "play gae:deploy" command?

Comment: I just solved my problem! (same config as you except 1.2.2). This big jar was in 2 different directories (I don't know why...). I removed from one (not lib dir) and it works! Thanks!